# How well can one know the rules in gambling before it's legally fraud?

Tags: united-states, fraud, gambling, singapore

A [Wired article from earlier this year](https://www.wired.com/2017/02/russians-engineer-brilliant-slot-machine-cheat-casinos-no-fix/) describes how a regulatory change in Russia (suddenly prohibiting most gambling) flooded the market there with old slot machines.  Some technically skilled people bought those machines and figured out the rules by which they operate in great detail.  They then used that knowledge to classify the operation of similar machines in the US, making predictions about what button-press timing would lead to improved payouts, and use those predictions to guide their gameplay and win money.

This seems very similar to a common purpose for entering casinos: people go in, at least thinking they know the rules of a game and intending to use that knowledge to win money.  Most of them do win money.  Only some walk away with a net gain, but those folks are then touted as example customers so that more people will be convinced to come in and place bets.

However, the folks who learned how the slot machines worked and use this to win by playing well were then prosecuted and jailed for years as perpetrators of **fraud**.  What is the particular law that they violated?  What is the threshold where it's considered fraud if you know *too well* how the game works?  Why does the casino get the option of prosecuting players as criminals instead of making the tradeoff between accepting losses vs. using better pseudorandom number generators?

Comment: If you have a PACER account, the details are here: https://www.plainsite.org/dockets/2nlxsngl2/missouri-eastern-district-court/usa-v-bliev-et-al/

Comment: Reverse-engineering the PRNG in an EGM is not "knowing the rules", otherwise looking through the cards in a blackjack deck would also just be "knowing the rules".

Comment: My bet is that the casino has a rule prohibiting use of predictive gadgetry, which customers have to agree to, in order to play (probably in a broad "will follow the rules" notice). That agreement, though, was knowingly false.

Comment: @Nij It is knowing the physical and mathematical rules.  Knowing the distribution of cards in a blackjack deck and being able to compute probabilities based on that distribution - including the portion of the distribution remaining after some cards have been revealed - is typically not prosecuted as fraud.

Comment: Knowing the distribution and knowing the exact pattern are two different things. Cracking a PRNG is like peeking at the deck after shuffling. That's why it's called a **pseudo**random generator in the first place. As user6726 says, there's also surely a ban on the use of computing or recording devices of any kind while playing, either by the casino or baked into law.

Comment: @Nij is there basis for that difference as being the answer?  Knowing the exact pattern is **fraud** while knowing less is not?  I thought casinos bore responsibility for sufficiently hiding the card-order information from patrons, and that patrons could legally use any information made visible by the casino.

Comment: Well no, that's not true everywhere and I would be surprised if it was true anywhere at all. The hand or spin or game is declared dead if any information that should not be revealed, happens to be. There are sometimes exceptions for e.g. one card shown from a deck that allow continued play, but two cards being exposed wrongly, means voiding the hand.

Comment: @Nij Does the casino bear the responsibility of declaring that hand dead, or are players legally required to turn in any winnings from that hand specifically at the end of the night (while still not being able to do anything about any losses)?  The analogy here would be that if the casino knows people have figured out what they have with these machines, it's the casino's responsibility to declare those games dead (and/or accept some losses if there are enough losing-money customers who like to play), not prosecute the customers for fraud.

Comment: The hand is dead and any money gained or lost must be returned (at least, in the law I trained and worked under). The casino may recover it immediately if the supervisor is paying attention and can get the dealer and player to comply, or it may take a surveillance review and a floor manager to identify and locate the player later. The hand is declared dead because that's the rules of the game. Fraud is not prosecuted by the casino, that's the job of police and the Crown, which has good reason to oppose such actions. They're two distinct outcomes.

Comment: @Nij If it's the casino's job to determine if the hand is dead and nullify resulting transactions, it should be the casino's job to determine if a slot machine is dead and remove these machines from play instead of continuing to rake in the dough from most people while criminally prosecuting those who wind up with a net gain from additional knowledge that they legally obtained.

Comment: First of all, again, the casino cannot and does not prosecute fraud. Secondly, the information is quite likely not legal to have, depending on license issues for which information is not available publicly, for obvious reason. Third, a dead hand does not make a deck unusable, a no spin does not require throwing away the wheel, and a void game does not require throwing away the machine. You're trying to defend crime based on your dislike of casinos. Get that fixed, then come back.

Comment: I'm trying to answer the question asked.  If I observe many spins and figure out that a wheel is weighted ever so slightly toward one side, and bet more on the appropriate numbers, is that fraud? Would it be the casino's job to fix that, or my job to forfeit any winnings while absorbing losses?  Where's the line of what's crime and what isn't?  Also, the casino does get the benefits of the prosecution, as it changes the cost/benefit analysis for the people who would be figuring out how to win more often at these games.

Comment: If you can crack PRNG, why don't you gamble online anonymously with bitcoin. And you don't have to worry if it's a fraud or not